# stale ObservedObject when using toolbar Picker and keyboardShortcut

Tags: macos, swiftui, keyboard-shortcuts

got 2 views
first view is ContentView:

```
NavigationSplitView { List (navlinks) ... } details: {
...
switch navlink {
case .console: ConsoleView(host: selectedHost),
...
}
}
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem {
       Picker(selection: $selectedHost) {
           ForEach(hosts) {
               Text($0.name).tag($0)
            }
        } label: {
          Text("host")
     }
    }
  }
```

second view:

```
ConsoleView: View {
@ObservedObject var host: RemoteHost

var body: some View {
TextEditor(...)
TextView(output...)
}
.toolbar {
ToolbarItem {
Button {
    print("exec against host: \(host.name)")
    } label: {
  Label("Execute", systemImage: "play.circle")
     }
}
.keyboardShortcut(.return, modifiers: .command)
}
}
```

```
class RemoteHost: ObservableObject {
@Published name: String
...
}
```

when the button is clicked, it prints the current selected host name. which is expected.
unexpected behavior:
sometimes, when the button is clicked, it prints the previously selected host name,
when the keyboardShortcut is triggered, it prints the previously selected host name,  after triggering twice, it prints current selected host name.
I wonder anybody can point where I'm wrong

tried add `.id(host)` to button. it fixes the first problem (button click problem).
and also adding `.help("Execute request against \(host.name)")` can fix button problem.
So I doubt it's a re-render problem. I need to somehow notify the system to re-render.
but the shortcut problem still exists.

Comment: In `ConsoleView` have you tried using `let host: RemoteHost`, or if you are modifying `host`, `@Binding var host: RemoteHost`. Can you show how you declare `RemoteHost`. Note that `ConsoleView(selectedHost)` does not make sense. Is the code you are showing us the real code that gives you problems?

Comment: edited. it's almost identical, just leave out irrelevant parts. also `ConsoleView(selectedHost)` should be `ConsoleView(host: selectedHost)`

Comment: can you show how you declare `selectedHost` in your `ContentView`. Is it something like: `@StateObject var selectedHost = RemoteHost()`